# Wikipedia opensearch API returns similar entries

Tags: search, wikipedia-api

I am using the Wikipedia opensearch API to retrieve some basic info from Wikipedia entries.

My code is as follows:

```
$persona = $_GET["persona"];
$pattern = '/\s+/';
$replacement = '_';
$url = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $persona);

$search = "https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=".$url;
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($search));
$t = $response[1];
$s = $response[2];
$u = $response[3];
```

Now, the problem is that it outputs info about similar entries. For example, if $url is "giuseppe_ferrandi", it returns info about "giuseppe_ferrandino". I assume "giuseppe_ferrandi" does not exist in Wikipedia, but I would prefer it to return nothing.

Comment: If you want exact matches instead of similar matches, why are you using the search API at all?

Comment: I wonder why the API doesn't allow exact matches. Are there any ways to force it?

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? If you want to simply know whether a page exists or not, why not use action=query&titles=$title ?

Comment: I use the API to get contents: `json_decode(file_get_contents($search));`

Comment: That really doesn't answer my question.

Comment: And your `action=query&titles=$title` returns no results at all.

Comment: For the existing or the non-existing title?